# Unable to add Sequential Workflow to Blank Site

Tags: workflow

I am trying to add a **Sequential Workflow** to a site as a list workflow. The site template I have chosen is **Blank Site**. While I am trying to add I am getting the following error.

[image]

I have already created a list (**Custom List**). I have this problem only with **Blank Site**. When I tried to do the same with **Team Site**, it worked fine.

I am using **Sharepoint Foundation** in **Windows 7**, I checked out the **Site collection Features** and could not find workflow feature in the list.

[image]

I checked out in **Sharepoint Server** installation in Windows **2008 Server R2**. The workflow feature is enabled by default for blank site, and this is working fine.

Screen shot from Sharepoint Server installation
[image]

Is it a limitation of **Sharepoint Foundation** or is there any workaround for this?

Any help will be appreciated, Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I got this

http://jeanpaulva.com/2012/10/02/workflow-history-task-not-found/

Here it is clearly explained the root causes and solutions.

Answer (score 1):

It does work in the Team Site because Workflow History and Workflow Tasks lists are created due to various site collection and site features which are activated automatically upon site creation (as part of the site definition).

The simplest is to go in the Site Collection Features and activate the Workflows feature.

Then you could get back to VS and try again.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It seems working fine in Sharepoint Server installation. But I am using Sharepoint Foundation on Windows-7. I have improved my question accordingly. Can you please take a look at that?

Comment: In SPF you do NOT have that particular feature as these are SharePoint Server Specific workflows!